# Oracle - How to get string after specified length and character

Tags: regex, oracle

I have multiple strings concated with ';'. I have to insert those words in a column which is unfortunatly limited to 500 characters. I want to cut the string at the last word before breaching the 500 character mark.

I tried using `REGEXP_SUBSTR (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '[^;]+', 1, 1))` but this query only returns the first string.

Altering the table is no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(col, 1, 500), ';[^;]*$', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

The logic here is to first truncate to 500 characters, using `SUBSTR`.  Then we remove any possible trailing word by removing the final semicolon and following (perhaps partial) word.

Comment: @Proxonator Apologies...use `SUBSTR` instead.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i needed.